# Is it possible to load balance MQTT traffic with Traefik 2.0 TCP feature?

Tags: tcp, load-balancing, mqtt, traefik

I am currently using Haproxy to load balance MQTT traffic to N dockerized mqtt brokers

Traefik 2.0 is out and can proxy TCP traffic, I am wondering if it is possible to load balance MQTT traffic to N dockerized mqtt brokers using Traefik as load balancer like you would do with Haproxy.

I tried some basic configuration using the official traefik doc, but i can't get the traffic upstream.

Has anyone tried this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I did it yesterday. I used the **VerneMQ** for MQTT broker and **Traefik** as a load balancer. The following configurations file are for **Docker Swarm**.

Here is the **docker-compose** configuration I use:

```
version: "3"

services:
    traefik:
        image: traefik:v2.1
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "1883:1883"
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - /dev/random:/dev/random
            - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.role == manager]
            labels:
                - traefik.enable=true
                - traefik.docker.network=net

                - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.home.gtheofilis.com`)
                - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=http
                - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal
                - traefik.http.services.dashboard.loadbalancer.server.port=9999

    vmq0:
        image: vernemq/vernemq
        environment:
            DOCKER_VERNEMQ_SWARM: 1
            DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ACCEPT_EULA: "yes"
            DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS: "on"
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.role == manager]
            labels:
                - traefik.enable=false

    vmq:
        image: vernemq/vernemq
        depends_on:
            - vmq0
        environment:
            DOCKER_VERNEMQ_SWARM: 1
            DOCKER_VERNEMQ_DISCOVERY_NODE: vmq0
            DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ACCEPT_EULA: "yes"
            DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS: "on"
        deploy:
            replicas: 3
            labels:
                - traefik.enable=true
                - traefik.docker.network=net
                - traefik.tcp.routers.mqtt.rule=HostSNI(`*`)
                - traefik.tcp.routers.mqtt.entrypoints=mqtt
                - traefik.tcp.services.mqtt.loadbalancer.server.port=1883

                - traefik.http.routers.mqtt_dashboard.rule=Host(`vernemq.home.gtheofilis.com`)
                - traefik.http.routers.mqtt_dashboard.service=mqtt_dashboard
                - traefik.http.routers.mqtt_dashboard.middlewares=auth
                - traefik.http.routers.mqtt_dashboard.entrypoints=http
                - traefik.http.services.mqtt_dashboard.loadbalancer.server.port=8888

networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: net
```

And this is my **traefik.toml** configuration file:

```
[api]
    dashboard = true

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.mqtt]
    address = ":1883"

[providers]
    [providers.docker]
        endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
        swarmMode = true
```

Comment: Why is `traefik.enable=false` set on the `vmq0` service?

Comment: I didn't need to expose vmq0 service, but if you like you can.

Comment: Did you create an overlay network `net` with `docker network create --driver=overlay net` and deploy using something like `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml verne`? I'm trying to implement same thing but looking at the logs `docker service logs verne_vmq0` I'm getting successful connection `[info] successfully connected to cluster node 'VerneMQ@10.0.21.10'` but then an error `[warning] terminate due to remote_node_not_available`. Any ideas, did you see something like this before?

Comment: Yes, this exactly how I did it. It was experimental; I didn't use it a lot so, unfortunately no I didn't get message like this.  So, I don't how to help you, sorry mate.

Comment: OK! Thanks. I can't even get the official script to work. I just raised an issues https://github.com/vernemq/docker-vernemq/issues/236. Think I will start with clean Ubuntu image and try again.

Comment: Final question, what OS and docker version did you use? I just tried on clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 and got the same.

Comment: I only remember OS version was Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Hmmm yes I tried on that. I wondering what can be different! It must be something with my network setup. Maybe it needs to be an attachable network?

Comment: Seems to be related to a bug in VerneMQ, it is possible with a little dancing https://github.com/vernemq/vernemq/issues/1593